# qdap package: bug in converting zero digits to "zero" words

Tags: r, numbers, text-processing, qdap

Before (as a rookie) I go submitting this as an R package bug, let me run it by y'all.  I think all of the following are good:

```
replace_number("123 0 boogie")
[1] "one hundred twenty three boogie"
replace_number("1;1 foo")
[1] "one;one foo"
replace_number("47 bar")
[1] "forty seven bar"
replace_number("0")
"zero"
```

I think all of the following are bad because "zero" is missing from the output:

```
replace_number("1;0 foo")
[1] "one; foo"
replace_number("00 bar")
[1] "bar"
replace_number("0x")
[1] "x"
```

Basically, I'd say that `replace_number()` is incapable of handling strings that contain the digit 0 (except for "0").  Is it a real bug?

Comment: You can file an issue. It can be a feature request or in the very least a message of warning in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you dig into the guts of `replace_number`:

```
 unlist(lapply(lapply(gsub(",([0-9])", "\\1", text.var), function(x) {
        if (!is.na(x) & length(unlist(strsplit(x, "([0-9])", 
            perl = TRUE))) > 1) {
            num_sub(x, num.paste = num.paste)
        }
        else {
            x
        }
    }), function(x) mgsub(0:9, ones, x)))
```

you can see that the problem occurs in `qdap:::num_sub`

```
qdap:::num_sub("101", num.paste = "combine") ## "onehundredone"
qdap:::num_sub("0", num.paste = "combine")   ## ""
```

Digging within that function, the issue occurs in `numb2word`, which has internal codes

```
ones <- c("", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", 
    "seven", "eight", "nine")
names(ones) <- 0:9
```

which convert zero values to blanks. If I were facing this problem myself I would fork the [qdap repo](https://github.com/trinker/qdap), go to [replace_number.R](https://github.com/trinker/qdap/blob/b966935a90a8dbeb5d660ff20f9208e9aca95ccf/R/replace_number.R), and try to change this in a *backward compatible* way so that `replace_number` could take a logical argument `blank_zeros=TRUE`, which got passed down to `numb2word` and did the right thing, e.g.

```
ones <- c(if (blank_zeros) "" else "zero",
          "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", 
    "seven", "eight", "nine")
```

In the meantime I have posted this on the [qdap issues list](https://github.com/trinker/qdap/issues/222).